# Do replaced quests reappear in Duelyst?

Tags: duelyst

In Duelyst, if I replace a quest, does it ever re-appear?

I've only ever skipped one quest ("play four games as [some faction]"), and I don't complete quests often enough to know for sure if it's going to come back or not.